# Facebook login in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am creating facebook login functionality for my website, but I am having some problems. Every time I call the login function it shows the popup, but doesn't display the user name and id of the users. It also doesn't not show the logout button. Any suggestions?

Here is the error and .js file:

> Error get -TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined in login function

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.facebook', ['ngRoute','ngFacebook'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/facebook', {
    templateUrl: 'facebook/facebook.html',
    controller: 'FacebookCtrl'
  });
}])

.config( function( $facebookProvider ) {
  $facebookProvider.setAppId('1752693171629646');
  $facebookProvider.setPermissions('email,public_profile,user_post,publish_actions,user_photos');
})
.run(function($rootScope){

      (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
})
.controller('FacebookCtrl', ['$scope','$facebook',function($scope,$facebook) {
$scope.isLoggedIn=false;

$scope.login =function()
{ 
    FB.login().then(function(){

        $scope.isLoggedIn=true;
        console.log($scope.isLoggedIn);
return $scope.isLoggedIn;
        refresh();

    });

}

$scope.logout =function()
{
    FB.logout().then(function(){

        $scope.isLoggedIn=false;


        refresh();



    });


    console.log($scope.isLoggedIn);
}

function refresh(){

     $facebook.api("/me").then(function(response){
        $scope.welcomeMsg = "Welcome "+ response.name;
        $scope.isLoggedIn = true;
        $scope.userinfo = response;
        console.log(response);



     }, function(err){

        $scope.welcomeMsg ="Please Login" ;
     });
}
refresh();
}]);
```

Html

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="FacebookCtrl">
 <div class="col-md-4">
  <h4> {{welcomeMsg}} </h4>
  <div ng-if= "isLoggedIn == false">
  <button type="button" class="btn bt-defualt" ng-click="login()">Login</button>
  </div>
   <div ng-if= "isLoggedIn == true">
  <button type="button" class="btn bt-defualt" ng-click="logout()">Logout</button>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
<div ng-if= "isLoggedIn == true" class="well">
<h4> profile data </h4>
<ul>
  <li>{{userinfo.id}}</li>

<li> {{userinfo.first_name}}</li>
 <li>{{userinfo.last_name}} </li>
 <li>{{userinfo.email}}</li>
 <li>{{userinfo.gender}}</li>
 <li>{{userinfo.locale}}</li>

</ul>

</div>
<div class="well">
<h4> PerMission </h4>
<ul>
  <li>..</li>



</ul>

</div>


  </div>

<div class="col-md-8">
  </div>
  <h1>Greeting to Facebook</h1>
  </div>
```

Comment: add `.error` callback to `FB.Login()` function to see what  error `FB` is returining while logging in.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at ChildScope.$scope.login (facebook.js:31)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:15126), <anonymous>:4:206)
    at expensiveCheckFn (angular.js:16213)
    at callback (angular.js:26592)
    at ChildScope.$eval (angular.js:17994)
    at ChildScope.$apply (angular.js:18094)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:26597)
    at defaultHandlerWrapper (angular.js:3546)
    at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (angular.js:3534)